# Ways to test on speech recognition module on android

Tags: android, testing, speech-recognition

I am new to android app development. I am currently developing an app using speech recognition module provided by android.

My app gets output from the speech recognition module and process the output to classify them into groups. This classification does not rely on machine learning, but just a rule/dictionary base classification/grouping.
I would like to know if there is a way to test the app scalable manner. For example, there is a certain size of dataset of text to synthesise its pronunciation and put them into the module and check the classification result.

I googled it for a few days but no luck so far.. If you know the test method for an app including speech recognition module, please advise me!
Thank you so much for your help in advance!

Comment: You can use some text-to-speech api to transform text to voice.

Comment: @simon5678 ah good idea. I checked text-to-speech apis and am surprised by the recent advancements. Thanks for your advice!